# Disable both shift keys and turn caps lock into a shift

Tags: ubuntu, x11, keyboard-layout

My Macbook Pro's keyboard is malfunctioning and both its shift keys are pressing erratically. Other than that, it is fine.

In Macos 10.11, I solved that problem by using karabiner.

In Linux, Xmodmap didn't worK. Is there some command on setxkbmap that would work?

Comment: I edited the file `/etc/default/keyboard` adding the line `XKBOPTIONS="caps:swapescape"` to swap my caps lock and my escape key for using Vim. I think you can disable keys as well by using this file. These changes are system wide for all users. I'd add an answer if I had time to look into it fully for you. Also, I'm on Debian. https://askubuntu.com/questions/342066/how-to-permanently-configure-keyboard  I also needed to install `console-common` and `console-data` for it to work (in Debian).

Comment: I think changes will take effect in `/etc/default/keyboard` by rebooting without having to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy program called [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html) that will let you do this.

Comment: Hello! So, I used it (which, by the way, has been renamed to karabiner), but I am using linux right now, and still haven't figured out a way to disable shift keys in ubuntu